# Hide graphicImage if image does not exist

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I have a graphicImage that takes its value from a servlet (called "picture" - it dynamically serves images stored on the server).

I would like to hide graphicImage when servlet returns null (no image was found).
I tried using FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResource() but it returns null even for correct URLs.

```
 <h:graphicImage value="/picture?name=#{myBean.name}" />
```

Comment: Do you want to hide image when myBean.name returns null?

Comment: no, I want to hide it when image that is returned by the servlet is null or does not exist

Comment: post some more code with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if i missunderstand you then sorry.

i would suggest two ways to hide this image:

1. you can check in any ControllerBean (myBean, or ...) if that image exists or not, and passing a rendered Property to JSF UI:

   `<h:graphicImage value="/picture?name=#{myBean.name}" rendered="pictureControler.isFound"/>`
2. or just add alt="" to that image, this image woun't be displayed then.

   `<h:graphicImage value="/picture?name=#{myBean.name}" alt=" "/>`

NOTE: the last one not tested but i think should work.